# Add item to fsproj through dotnet CLI

Tags: f#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am using the dotnet CLI (v1.0.4) to create and manage projects.  I have found the documentation for and have successfully created projects using the CLI with commands such as the following:

```
dotnet new console -lang F# -o src/myConsoleApp
```

I have also figured out how to add references to other projects, DLLs, and Nuget packages.

The one thing that I can't figure out how to do is add a new compile item to the fsproj file through a CLI command.  Does such a command exist?  I can manually edit the fsproj file and add a new `<Compile Include="..." />`, but that seems too easy to make typos and other errors.  I have been using Visual Studio for many years, so perhaps I am under the wrong impression that there should be another way than to manually edit the project file to add a file to a project?

Comment: I don't know the dotnet CLI so I can't answer your question, but there's project-file functionality in the [Ionide](http://ionide.io/) extension to VS Code, if you're using VS Code. Install the `Ionide-fsharp` extension (and you might as well install Ionide-FAKE and Ionide-Paket while you're doing so), and you should be able to add files to the project in a graphical view. While that's not what you're asking for, it might help.

Comment: @rmunn Are you referring to the file explorer and/or the project explorer in VSCode Ionide?  While I do see minimal options to move files up/down and remove them, I do not see an add option.  Not only that, but the extension must not be made for dotnet core projects.  Selecting any of the options does not seem to do anything.

Comment: I mean the project explorer. The Ionide changelog for the latest version mentioned adding an "add file to project" feature in the project view, as I recall. (On my phone right now so it's hard to check.) I know there was mention of how Ionide supports the new .Net Core fsproj format (even before Visual Studio 2017 did), but I can't easily check the details right now.

Comment: Ionide-fsharp for vscode does not support .Net Core 2.0 fsproj file format yet -- if that's the case you're in. I had the same problem, and visual studio 2017 can add files to the project.

Comment: @GangLiang Thank you for the additional comment. I understand that Visual Studio does have ways to add files to the project. I was looking to get new files added without using Visual Studio, but to use the CLI. Perhaps whatever mechanism that Visual Studio uses is accessible from outside of the IDE as well and I can use that.